# Mail server to receive all mail to file system

Tags: email, testing

We are developing a system that sends a lot of e-mails. For our testing purposes we would like to set up a mail server (smarthost) that accepts ALL mail to ALL domains, and then simply saves the mails to the local file system.

I would like hints in how to set up such a server.

Comment: Which SMTP/MTA server do you use as the smart host?

Comment: Currently using Postfix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can deploy Postfix mail server with little changes of default configuration**. See below.

Create transport map and open to edit:

```
> /etc/postfix/transport
```

Add the following:

```
* local:some_local_user
```

In `main.cf`:

```
luser_relay = some_local_user@your_domain.tld
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

Replace `some_local_user` with any existing user on your server.

Run one by one:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/transport
postmap /etc/aliases
service postfix reload
```

Check working. To do this you need to connect to your server with any mail client (or with your app) to 25 tcp port.

---

If you are a developer then you may be familar with Docker. And you can use Docker to build container with Postfix & Dovecot.

You can use this [source](https://github.com/bissquit/postfix-dovecot-maildir) to build image and run container.

Comment: Thank you. I get one small problem. If mail is addressed to a_local_user@anydomain and a_local_user exists on the machine it gets delivered to that local user. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: My method explained above assume that all mails will delivered to local user some_local_user. To which user do you need to deliver emails? Or you need to send all mails to /dev/null?